# How can I sort an excel sheet based upon the word frequency in "each cell" (similarity of the cell content"

Tags: excel, sorting

Suppose I have an excel sheet like such:

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column A</th>
    <th>Column B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>This is a sentence. There is a lot of words over here, and sometimes there are special characters and symbols too. the content for this cell is similar (in word content) to the one in the cell of the third row.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>A completely different cell </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>This is another sentence. There are a lot of words over here too. Notice that the content for this cell is similar to the one in cell of the first row.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to sort the data based on the *content* of the cell data. The cell data does *not* match exactly but if we judge by the frequency of the words then we can find some level of similarity in the cells.

I need to sort an excel sheet based on the word frequency so that, in this example, the rows 1 & 3 would get sorted together.

How can such a sort be applied?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have pasted HTML?

Comment: @QHarr I just wanted to show the tables clearly. The sentences are lengthy in second columns and if I used the ordinary text then they would wrap up and look confusing.

Comment: Good point well made. Is row 3 actually row 3?

Comment: @QHarr Nopes. I used the values randomly. Wait. Let me change the values to reflect the row numbers so that it'll be less confusing to people. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: That is one heck of a tricky, computationally expensive requirement. I have some pretty fast FuzzyMatch code that uses a cascading triage of approaches including partial match, common alias checking, and Levershtein Differencing, but it's only good for comparing one word against another. This is many times more complicated. How many cells are we talking here? And what kind of word count range across them? Can you elaborate more on the business need you're trying to address? (This often helps folks not only get to grips with the problem, but also perhaps suggest a left-field solution).